# Server functions not called from client

Tags: .net, azure, websocket, signalr

I have a problem when using SignalR trough Azure (ASP .NET). I have set up my server hub and the generated js client hub gets all server functions from the server hub, but when I call the server functions on the client, they are not called on the server.

On the messages tab in Chrome on the websocket, I can the messages are sent on the open connection to azure but somewhere on the way from azure to the server they dissappear.

Anyone else had the same problem and have a clue what might be the issue?

Log:

```
Microsoft.Azure.SignalR Information: 0 : [Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport]Starting transport. Transfer mode: Binary. Url: 'wss://xxxx.service.signalr.net/aspnetserver/?hub=testing.startup_testing.startup&cid=xxxxc'.
    Microsoft.Azure.SignalR Information: 0 : [Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport]Starting transport. Transfer mode: Binary. Url: 'wss://xxxx.service.signalr.net/aspnetserver/?hub=testing.startup_negguhub&cid=xxxx'.
    Microsoft.Azure.SignalR Information: 0 : [Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport]Starting transport. Transfer mode: Binary. Url: 'wss://xxxx.service.signalr.net/aspnetserver/?hub=testing.startup_xxxx&cid=xxxx'.
    Microsoft.Azure.SignalR Information: 0 : [Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.StrongServiceConnectionContainer]Hub 'NegguHub' is now connected to '(Primary)https://xxxx.service.signalr.net'.
    Microsoft.Azure.SignalR Information: 0 : [Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.StrongServiceConnectionContainer]Hub 'xxxx' is now connected to '(Primary)https://xxxx.service.signalr.net'.
    Microsoft.Azure.SignalR Information: 0 : [Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.StrongServiceConnectionContainer]Hub 'Testing.Startup' is now connected to '(Primary)https://xxxx.service.signalr.net'.
    Microsoft.Azure.SignalR Error: 0 : [Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.AspNet.ServiceConnection]Error when processing messages. Id: dea3a65d-3785-4a49-9821-73eb6552306c
    Microsoft.Azure.SignalR Error: 0 : [Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.AspNet.ServiceConnection]Error when processing messages. Id: dea3a65d-3785-4a49-9821-73eb6552306c
    Microsoft.Azure.SignalR Error: 0 : [Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.AspNet.ServiceConnection]Error when processing messages. Id: dea3a65d-3785-4a49-9821-73eb6552306c
    Microsoft.Azure.SignalR Error: 0 : [Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.AspNet.ServiceConnection]Error when processing messages. Id: dea3a65d-3785-4a49-9821-73eb6552306c
    Microsoft.Azure.SignalR Error: 0 : [Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.AspNet.ServiceConnection]Error when processing messages. Id: dea3a65d-3785-4a49-9821-73eb6552306c
    Microsoft.Azure.SignalR Error: 0 : [Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.AspNet.ServiceConnection]Error when processing messages. Id: dea3a65d-3785-4a49-9821-73eb6552306c
    Microsoft.Azure.SignalR Error: 0 : [Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.AspNet.ServiceConnection]Error when processing messages. Id: dea3a65d-3785-4a49-9821-73eb6552306c
    Microsoft.Azure.SignalR Error: 0 : [Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.AspNet.ServiceConnection]Error when processing messages. Id: dea3a65d-3785-4a49-9821-73eb6552306c
    Microsoft.Azure.SignalR Error: 0 : [Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.AspNet.ServiceConnection]Error when processing messages. Id: dea3a65d-3785-4a49-9821-73eb6552306c
    Microsoft.Azure.SignalR Error: 0 : [Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.AspNet.ServiceConnection]Error when processing messages. Id: dea3a65d-3785-4a49-9821-73eb6552306c
    Microsoft.Azure.SignalR Error: 0 : [Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.AspNet.ServiceConnection]Error when processing messages. Id: dea3a65d-3785-4a49-9821-73eb6552306c
    Microsoft.Azure.SignalR Error: 0 : [Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.AspNet.ServiceConnection]Error when processing messages. Id: dea3a65d-3785-4a49-9821-73eb6552306c
```

Comment: it would be help if you could share your code

Comment: It would also help to know the version of SignalR you're using, and whether you're self-hosting SignalR within a web app, or if you're using the SignalR Service.

Comment: Its very hard to give out the code, but I have followed the exact same way as they do in this example: 
https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples/tree/master/aspnet-samples/ChatRoom

In the asrs log, every time I send the message from the client I get this in the log:
Microsoft.Azure.SignalR Error: 0 : [Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.AspNet.ServiceConnection]Error when processing messages. Id: 88d8a703-68ac-4ee1-ac67-b11f2a5bf177

So clearly its also connection between the client and the server, its seems something is wrong in the message the server receives